# Cryto Failing to Decrypt a String

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to decrypt a string but test keeps failing and I cannot seem to figure out the issue.
Here are the files involved:

**Encryptor.js**

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto'

const hashAlgorithm = 'sha256';
const encryptAlgorithm = 'aes192';
const textEncoding = 'hex';
const encryptionKey = "some secret key";

export const getHash = text => {
  try {
    const encryptedData = crypto.createHmac(hashAlgorithm, encryptionKey);
    encryptedData.setEncoding(textEncoding)
                .end(text, () => encryptedData.read())
    return encryptedData;        
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

export const encrypt = text => {
  if (!text)
    throw Error('Text may not be blank');
  try {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipher(encryptAlgorithm, encryptionKey);
    let cipherText = '';
    cipher.on('readable', () => {
      let data = cipher.read();
      if (data)
        cipherText += data.toString(textEncoding);
    });
    cipher.on('end', () => cipherText);
    cipher.write(text);
    cipher.end();
  }
  catch (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
}

export const decrypt = text => {
  if (!text)
    throw Error('Decrypt: Text may not be blank');
  try {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipher(encryptAlgorithm, encryptionKey);
    let decrypted = '';

    decipher.on('readable', () => {
      const data = decipher.read();
      if (data)
        return decrypted += data.toString('utf8');
    });
    decipher.on('end', () => decrypted);
    decipher.write(text, textEncoding);
    decipher.end();
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

**Encryptor.test.js**

```
import {getHash, encrypt, decrypt } from './Encryptor.js';


const dataString = "Important information must always be encypted"

it('Should create a hashed message FROM STRING', () => {
  expect(getHash(dataString)).not.toEqual(dataString)
})

it('Should encrypt the message FROM STRING', () => {
  expect(encrypt(dataString)).not.toEqual(dataString)
})

it('Should decrypt the message FROM ENCRYPTED STRING', () => {
  expect(decrypt(encrypt(dataString))).toEqual(dataString)
})
```

As far as I understand, this code is fine. However, when I run the test, the last one fails with this trace:

[image]

If I pass a literal string to the decrypt function like so:

```
it('Should decrypt the message FROM ENCRYPTED STRING', () => {
  expect(decrypt("encypted")).toEqual(dataString)
})
```

the returned results are `undefined` and I also get the `error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length` error

[image]

I followed almost exactly the examples [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher) with no success.

Comment: You never actually return anything.

Comment: Yes, but why does the encrypt test pass even though I am not returning anything even there?

Comment: Why wouldn't it pass? `undefined` does not equal your string.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am now returning something but the test still won't pass, with the same issue

Comment: You still aren't returning anything.  Your function needs to be async; use promises.

Comment: Aren't arrow functions, or at least the way I have used them supposed to return anything after the arrow?

Comment: Only expression arrow functions, not blocks.